# Prove there is a square of a rational number between any two positive real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I'm doing this problem and the solution is below. I don't understand why this solution proved $m^2 \le x$ firstly? Any help, thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.

Instead of addressing the quoted proof, I give a quite short proof of the more general result that for any positive integer $k$ there exists a rational number $r$ such that $x < r^k < y$, without assuming any knowledge of the existence of $k^\text{th}$ roots. (Taking $k = 2$ doesn't make the proof any shorter.)

For all positive integers $k, p$,
$$
\frac{(p + 1)^k}{p^k} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{p}\right)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\frac{1}{p^j} \leqslant 1 + \sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}\frac{1}{p} = 1 + \frac{2^k - 1}{p}.
$$

Given $y > x > 0$, define
$$
h = \frac{(2^k - 1)x}{y - x}.
$$

Then
$$
\tag{1}\label{ineq:p}
p > h \implies \frac{(p + 1)^k}{p^k} < \frac{y}{x}.
$$

There exists a positive integer $q$ such that
$$
\tag{2}\label{ineq:q}
q^kx \geqslant (1 + h)^k.
$$

For instance, it is enough to take any $q$ such that
$$
q \geqslant (1 + h)\left(1 + \frac{\max\{1 - x, 0\}}{kx}\right).
$$
The inequality just given is equivalent to the conjunction of  $q \geqslant 1 + h$ with
$$
1 + k\left(\frac{q}{1 + h} - 1\right) \geqslant \frac{1}{x},
$$
and therefore it implies
$$
\frac{q^k}{(1 + h)^k} = \left(\frac{q}{1 + h}\right)^k = \left(1 + \frac{q}{1 + h} - 1\right)^k \geqslant 1 + k\left(\frac{q}{1 + h} - 1\right) \geqslant \frac{1}{x},
$$
as required.

Take any value of $q$ satisfying \eqref{ineq:q}.

The inequality
$$
\tag{3}\label{ineq}
p^k \leqslant q^kx
$$
holds for some values of $p$ (for example, $p = 1$), but not for all (for example, not for $p = q\left(1 + \lceil{x}\rceil\right)$).

Therefore, there exists a unique largest value of $p$ for which \eqref{ineq} holds.

For this value of $p$, we have $(p + 1)^k > q^kx \geqslant (1 + h)^k$, and therefore $p > h$.

Invoking \eqref{ineq:p} and \eqref{ineq}, we get
$$
q^kx < (p + 1)^k < p^k\frac{y}{x} \leqslant q^ky,
$$
and therefore finally
$$
x < \left(\frac{p + 1}{q}\right)^k < y.
$$

Comment: Is there an even simpler proof by contradiction possible? There exists a rational $x<m<y$. Assume $m\gt 1$, fix some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $A=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}: r^n \lt m\}$, $B=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}: r^n \gt m\}$. Let $a=\sup{A}, b=\inf{B}$, we claim either $a=m$ or $b=m$. Assume the opposite; that is $a \lt m \lt b$. There exist rationals $q_1, q_2$ such that (1) $a \lt q_1 \lt m \lt q_2 \lt b$, and such that (2) ${q_1}^n \geq m$ and ${q_2}^n \leq m$. The contradiction between (1) and (2) shows either $a=m$ or $b=m$ (or both), which easily gives the case for $m\gt 1$. Is there a flaw here?

Comment: @MoedPolBollo I don't think there is any flaw in your argument, and I think what this shows is that it is simpler to prove the existence of $n^\text{th}$ roots than to try to prove the result in the question without using the existence of $n^\text{th}$ roots (at least by the method in my comment or the method in the textbook).

Comment: P.S. I forgot to mention that one intended advantage of my argument is that it includes the case $k = 1$: indeed, it was designed to generalise an argument for the density of the rationals in the reals in the simplest way I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to prove that there is a real number $m\geqslant0$ such that $m^2\leqslant x$ which is such that for any rational number $r>m$ you have $r^2>x$. So, if you add a small number to $m$ (the $\delta$ of the proof), then $(m+\delta)^2>x$. So, what you have to do next is to prove that you can find such a $\delta$ so that

- $m+\delta\in\mathbb Q$;
- $x<(m+\delta)^2<y$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm a little confused about how this proof show that $m + \delta \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Cathy $m + \delta $ is not assumed to be in $\mathbb{Q} $. Rather $m$ is a real number which satisfies $m \leq r \quad \forall r \in A$ and $m^2 \leq x$. Then $\delta$ is chosen such that $m \lt m + \delta$ and $(m+ \delta)^2 \leq y$. The last part of the proof is then just the assumption that there must exist a rational $r$ such that $m \lt r \lt m + \delta$ (since otherwise $m+ \delta$ would be a lower bound of $A$ greater than $m$, which is a contradiction).

Comment: @MoedPolBollo Thanks! I just find I still confused about why we need $m^2 \le x$?

Comment: @Cathy I made a mistake in my answer. It is not necessarily true that $m+\delta\in\mathbb Q$. But it follows from the definition of $m$ that there's some rational $r\in(x+x+\delta)$ such that $x<r^2<y$.

Comment: @Cathy The defining property of elements of $A$, is that their square is greater than $x$. $m$ is the infimum of $A$, which means it is the largest real number less than any element of $A$. So, think of any interval: $(m, m + a)$, then the fact that $m= \inf{A}$ means that there is always a rational $r \in A$ in this interval, and we can shrink this interval down as small as we like. This is essentially what the proof shows. So I guess you can think of the fact that $m^2 \leq x$ as acting like an anchor, which pulls the rationals down to where we want them.